# Update column to any non-unknown value of the column in another row with the same ID

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, sequelize.js, greatest-n-per-group

I have a PostgreSQL table in which some of the rows are dirty because at point of data entry the `gender` of the record is "unknown" although it always stays the same indicated by its `object_id`, which is the unique identifier of the object.

```
object_id                           gender
511E1AC7128EE2E74349896B55461F27    Unknown
511E1AC7128EE2E74349896B55461F27    Unknown
511E1AC7128EE2E74349896B55461F27    Male
56665EA256AB3757CDFA6C1CB4334C91    Female
56665EA256AB3757CDFA6C1CB4334C91    Female
56665EA256AB3757CDFA6C1CB4334C91    Unknown
56665EA256AB3757CDFA6C1CB4334C91    Unknown
55C3BFDBD327396E912604D6E635D59B    Unknown
55C3BFDBD327396E912604D6E635D59B    Unknown
55C3BFDBD327396E912604D6E635D59B    Female
```

Therefore, I want to update my table to be like this:

```
object_id                           gender
511E1AC7128EE2E74349896B55461F27    Male
511E1AC7128EE2E74349896B55461F27    Male
511E1AC7128EE2E74349896B55461F27    Male
56665EA256AB3757CDFA6C1CB4334C91    Female
56665EA256AB3757CDFA6C1CB4334C91    Female
56665EA256AB3757CDFA6C1CB4334C91    Female
56665EA256AB3757CDFA6C1CB4334C91    Female
55C3BFDBD327396E912604D6E635D59B    Female
55C3BFDBD327396E912604D6E635D59B    Female
55C3BFDBD327396E912604D6E635D59B    Female
```

In which all the "unknown" columns are converted to whatever non-unknown value the `object_id` has in /some other entry/. Is there a way I can do this in PostgreSQL - or - even better - Sequelize (Javascript ORM for SQL databases?)

Comment: If such a thing is done it would be a patchwork solution at best because your data appears not be normalized. If anyone was to give you a patch work solution he would still need to know what object_state looks like

Comment: The usual suspects are missing: table definition and Postgres version.

Comment: I took the liberty to remove the noise around `object_state`, which was orthogonal to the question and only served to distract.

Comment: It's normalized. Just the other columns of `object_state` are irrelevant to the question, and I wanted to assert that there are more columns that can have varied information that explains why there are multiple entries with the same UUID. It isn't really a primary key of this table (although it is a primary key of another lookup table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is incomplete so I am assuming current Postgres version 9.5 and this table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE object (
   object_id uuid PRIMARY KEY  -- ideally a UUID
 , gender    text              -- could probably be boolean
 -- rest irrelevant
   );
```

Then the solution can be:

```
UPDATE object o
SET    gender = sub.gender
FROM (
   SELECT object_id, min(gender) AS gender
   FROM   object
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub
WHERE  o.object_id = sub.object_id
AND    o.gender IS DISTINCT FROM sub.gender;
```

You need the subquery because aggregate or window functions are not allowed in `UPDATE` directly.

The aggregate function `min()` happens to work because the `text` *'Unknown'* sorts after *'Female'* and *'Male'*. It would also work for `boolean` (where 'Unknown' would be `NULL`), and `min()` and `max()` ignore `NULL` values.

The last `WHERE` condition is optional, but it's wise to include it to avoid empty updates. Can be simplified to `o.gender <> sub.gender` if the column is defined `NOT NULL`;

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

Why would it be ideal to use the data type `uuid`?

- [Would index lookup be noticeably faster with char vs varchar when all values are 36 chars](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89429/would-index-lookup-be-noticeably-faster-with-char-vs-varchar-when-all-values-are/89433#89433)

Comment: thanks. to add on to this, I think it would be good to switch "unknown" to NULL, so then I would change the second line to:
`SET    gender = NULLIF(sub.gender, 'Unknown')` ?

Comment: @user3264659: Yes, and drop the last line, since you want to update *all* rows in this case.